# Add horizontal line to ggplot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot2 to draw multiple line with different colors in one plot and then add a separate horizontal line. My code is as below. It works well until I run the final line `p + geom_hline(yintercept=400)`. All the lines become black and legend on the right side disappear.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
library(ggplot2)
mry <- do.call(rbind, by(movies, round(movies$rating), function(df) { 
       nums <- tapply(df$length, df$year, length) 
        data.frame(rating=round(df$rating[1]), year = as.numeric(names(nums)), 
        number=as.vector(nums)) 
        }))
p<-qplot(year, number, data=mry, group=rating, geom="line",xlab = 'year',
     ylab = 'number')

p + geom_line()

p + geom_line(aes(colour = rating))

p + geom_hline(yintercept=400)
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not saving the intermediate steps. Each plot is adding just that one thing to `p`. If you want to keep the piece you just added, you'd need to do something like:

```
p <- p + geom_line(aes(colour = rating))
```

Answer (score 2):

A concrete solution to your question above could be to simply move your last line of code, `p + geom_hline(yintercept=400)`, up to be part of the second to last line.

This would make your last line of code look like this, `p + geom_line(aes(colour = rating)) + geom_hline(yintercept=400)`. You could also combine your three last lines into `p + geom_line(aes(colour = rating)) + geom_hline(yintercept=400)`.

Basically restating what joran suggests, but I'm trying to make it more concrete.