# How Can I Increase Space Between Bars With ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(G, aes(x=State, y=Score, fill=State))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+ 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Please help me make  more elegant to read.

**[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOOag.png)**
+ I wanna use a line in x at the score of 236, tried 
    abline( v=236)

did not work!

Comment: Why are you adding the python and excel tags? As far as I know, Excel doesn't have `ggplot`, and your question seems to be "how do I do X in ggplot".

Comment: Also, please don't change the goals of your question after people have added answers. "How do I increase space between bars with ggplot?" is a good focused question. "How do I add a horizontal line to ggplot?" is also a good focused question. Ask them as separate questions, don't edit the second in after the first has been answered. (Also, maybe search a little first in the the `ggplot2` tag, e.g., [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10748180/903061), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13254691/903061))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of bars. You can make the bars narrower by specifying their `width` inside `geom_bar()` (as a proportion, 1 is touching, 0.5 is equal amounts of bar and gap, the default is 0.9).

```
ggplot(G, aes(x = State, y = Score, fill = State)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Also note that the `position = "dodge"` isn't doing anything in your example.

For a plot with that many bars, if you want them all labeled, I would suggest adding `+ coord_flip()` to your plot - usually it's easier to have lots of vertical space than lots of horizontal space, and the long labels won't overlap. When you have over 50 bars, you're going to need a fair amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me

```
barplot(c(1,2,3,4),space=c(1,1,1,1))  # equally spaced bars as expected

barplot(c(1,2,3,4),space=c(1,20,1,1))  # massive gap before the 2nd bar

barplot(c(1,2,3,4),space=c(20,1,1,1))  # the same as the first plot
```